# CSS Grab an Element's position

Tags: javascript, css

Hey everyone can someone show me how I would be able to grab an element's current position?

Doesn't do much. All it demonstrate is a button click and grabs the item I want references.

I want to be able to grab it's current position so when I click a button i can display something on top of it.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lkmjzy9d/`ignore this <code block> apparently this needs to be here when displaying a jsfiddle link??? idk....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can use

```
element.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

Comment: Yes thank you this is also a nice method to avoid using a whole library for one function

Answer (score 1):

You can get an elements position using jQuery position()
Check the following code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var element = $("#Randomitem");
          console.log(element.position());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myButton">Click Me</button>
      <span id="Randomitem">Random Item</span>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's perfect!! Idk why I couldn't see the position method. I'll mark this as an answer when the time limit is up

Answer (score 0):

CSS isn't a scripting language. Therefore you'll need to use something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/).